# Connection Automatically Timedout (Session Timeout)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am currently working on an application in which the user logins to view/edit multiple types of report, so other users can see what changes have been made. But sometimes when the user is going to a new page the session automatically timeouts.

My code is:

```
Function Check_Access(ByVal strModule As String) As String
        Dim drAccess As SqlClient.SqlDataReader, strUser As String
        GetNetworkName()
        strUser = HttpContext.Current.Session("LOGON_USER")

        drAccess = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strConnOASIS, "Oasis.dbo.p_RPT_Check_Accessibility", strModule, strUser)

    If drAccess.HasRows Then
        If drAccess.Read() Then
            Return drAccess.GetString(0)
        End If
    End If
    drAccess.Close()
    Return "0"
End Function
```

The source error is:

```
Line 45:         strUser = HttpContext.Current.Session("LOGON_USER")
Line 46: 
Line 47:         drAccess = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strConnOASIS, "Oasis.dbo.p_RPT_Check_Accessibility", strModule, strUser) //Error
Line 48: 
Line 49:         If drAccess.HasRows Then
```

And lastly the Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]

System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +445
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +132

 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +195

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122

Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters) +412

Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, String spName, Object[] parameterValues) +442

OasisInclude.GlobalFunctions.Check_Access(String strModule) in E:\Danish\VSO\OasisRedesign\Dev\Oasis\OasisInclude\GlobalFunctions.vb:47

Residential.Residential.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Danish\VSO\OasisRedesign\Dev\Oasis\Oasis\Residential\Residential.aspx.vb:56

System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109

System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68

System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3321
```

Comment: The application is failing to obtain a database connection. Make sure you are closing all the database connections you open. You can also increase the size of the database connection pool but ultimately you'll likely to hit the same error sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

You are never closing the data reader if it returns data. All those open data readers are holding your database connections causing the error.

To fix it, change the code to:

```
Function Check_Access(ByVal strModule As String) As String
        Dim drAccess As SqlClient.SqlDataReader, strUser As String
        GetNetworkName()
        strUser = HttpContext.Current.Session("LOGON_USER")

        drAccess = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strConnOASIS, "Oasis.dbo.p_RPT_Check_Accessibility", strModule, strUser)

        Try
           If drAccess.HasRows Then
              If drAccess.Read() Then
                Return drAccess.GetString(0)
              End If
           End If
        Finally
          drAccess.Close()
        End Try
    Return "0"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. your solution really helped me alot.i just wanted to ask to something wont there be a problem if return string comes before the connection closes.

Comment: That's why the reader close is in the Finally construct; it will always run.